# Javascript validation allowing spaces, hyphens, and foreign characters in names

Tags: javascript, validation, special-characters

I'm currently using code like this:

```
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (f_name.value.length > 1 && f_name.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        // success
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerText = "<img src='images/icons/cross.png' class='mark'>";
        // fail
    }
```

However, `alphaExp` only accounts for upper- and lower-case English characters. How can I allow for foreign letters (é, å, ü etc) and spaces/hyphens?

Comment: Perhaps you might find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings. Use that code to remove accents, then just check with your current regexp (and use `[a-zA-Z -]`).

Comment: I currently have /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/ but it's not working. What have I done wrong?

Comment: A problem could be the fact you're using match instead of test...
Use `alphaExp.test(f_name.value)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can try following regex:

```
/^[a-z- \xC0-\xFF]+$/i
```

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/don242ay/)

```js
function validate() {
  var regex = /^[a-z- \xC0-\xFF]+$/i;
  var value = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = regex.test(value) ? "valid": "incorrect"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

[Encoding Reference](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Insert `\s` to allow spaces.
Add the others letters or symbols you want match.

`var alphaexp = /^[a-zA-Z\séåü]+$/`

Comment: `\s` also accepts tabs and other spacial characters (and no hypens :)).

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z\-\séåü]+$/`. I assumed he means all space chars :o